# Como deshabilitar casillas de las fechas en un jdatechooser en java

Tags: java, date, calendar, jcalendar, jdatechooser

Estoy intentando hacer un calendario para citas, la idea es que no pueda seleccionar ni sábados ni domingos en el calendario. Alguno tiene idea como puedo hacer?
si no se puede, alguna forma de que cuando toque el domingo le avise que ese día no se puede
Muchas gracias

intente con JDateChooser.setSelectableDateRange pero solo es entre un rango de fechas

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Desconocía esa clase pero por los ejemplos que he podido encontrar y basándome principalmente en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753026/2553194) necesitas establecer un `IDateEvaluator` que devuelva aquellas fechas que sean inválidas.

Aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo funcional con un `JDateChooser` en el que establezco como evaluador de fechas mi propio MyDateEvaluator que implementa el interfaz `IDateEvaluator`. De aquellos métodos que se requiere implementar solo he incluido código en isInvalid, el resto he dejado la implementación por defecto que me ha generado IntelliJ

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestJDateChooser {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        dateChooser.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 20);
        dateChooser.getJCalendar().setMinSelectableDate(new Date());
        dateChooser.getJCalendar().getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(new MyDateEvaluator());
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(dateChooser);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Aquí mi clase MyDateEvaluator

```
import com.toedter.calendar.IDateEvaluator;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MyDateEvaluator implements IDateEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getSpecialTooltip() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return (dayOfWeek == GregorianCalendar.SATURDAY) || (dayOfWeek == GregorianCalendar.SUNDAY);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getInvalidTooltip() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Como ves solo he rellenado el método isInvalid donde he empleado GregorianCalendar para determinar si la fecha es sábado o domingo.